# ASP checkbox value incorrect when AutoPostBack is set to false

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-7

I am still relatively new at VB.Net and Visual Studio and I'm assuming that this is a simple fix, but I'm not sure.

I have an asp:checkbox control on an aspx page I am working on.  This checkbox is within a custom control and previously was posting back every time it was clicked.  I am in the process of ajaxifying the page and have come across a problem.  When I remove the attribute AutoPostBack="True" from the asp:checkbox, the vb code returns `False` when I check `myCheckbox.checked` (this is on a postback else where on the page what has not be ajaxified), even though I can see the box is indeed checked.

I am assuming that because the checkbox no longer posts back, for some reason the VB code (or the view state maybe) doesn't see it as having been checked.  Is this correct, and if so, how to I correct it?

Comment: It would be helpful to have a minimal working example of this issue. It is unclear on what you are using to "ajaxify" the page, be it update panels, jquery, or something else, and it would be helpful to understand more about your custom control. That said, here's a few guesses: if you are using update panels, ensure your control is within the update panel. If your custom control is a composite control, ensure that controls are added to the collection in the `CreateChildControls()` method, and that property setter/getters call `EnableChildControls()`.

Comment: I would love to, but because of NDA and the size of the file, I don't know if I can.  I will look into what you posted here and post an update on what I find.

Comment: I can say that we use jQuery for the ajax call, but it is not on the ajax call that we have this issue, it is one of the postback calls still on the page

Comment: I changed it to an input of type checkbox and now it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the checkbox from an ASP control to be an HTML input of type checkbox and now it works :)

Answer (score -1):

> I am assuming that because the checkbox no longer posts back, for some reason the VB code (or the view state maybe) doesn't see it as having been checked.

This is correct, your toggling of the checkbox is happening only on the client side, so your server side is unaware of the change.

Comment: -1 This is not correct. When the PostBack is generated, the value of the checkbox's Checked property should be true.